# Configuring Wireless on Cisco 851W

Tags: cisco, router, wifi

Either a powersurge or something caused our router's configuration to get wiped, and our last backup was before the wireless network was setup.

We have not been able to reconfigure the wireless since then, so was curious if anyone here would be able to determine what configuration is needed.

We are using a Cisco 851W running 12.4(15)T9

We would like to use WPA encryption, and have it on the same network as the rest of the office network.

Config file is below:

```
User Access Verification

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3857 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
no service dhcp
!
hostname BOB
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 *********************
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
no ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
no ip bootp server
ip domain name BOB.com
ip name-server 61.11.1.1
ip name-server 61.11.1.2
!
!
!
username BOBB privilege 15 password 7 *************************
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 10
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet1
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet2
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet3
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet4
 description WAN Connection$ETH-WAN$
 ip address 61.11.1.14 255.255.254.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 !
 encryption mode ciphers tkip
 speed basic-1.0 basic-2.0 basic-5.5 6.0 9.0 basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0
 54.0
 station-role root
 no cdp enable
!
interface Dot11Radio0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 no cdp enable
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface Dot11Radio0.20
 ip access-group Guest-ACL in
 no cdp enable
!
interface Vlan1
 description Internal Network
 ip address 192.168.2.60 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip nat enable
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 61.11.2.14
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet4 overload
!
ip access-list extended Guest-ACL
 deny   ip any 192.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip any any
!
access-list 1 permit 192.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 remark SDM_ACL Category=2
access-list 100 permit ip 192.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
no cdp run
!
control-plane
!
!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps380/products_configuration_example09186a00808a8d80.shtml

Configure the SSID for WPA-PSK Authentication

Complete these actions:

Enable the radio interface.

In order to enable the radio interface, go to the DOT11 radio interface configuration mode and assign an SSID to the interface.

```
router#interface dot11radio0
router#no shutdown
router#ssid wpa-shared
```

In order to enable WPA key management, first configure the WPA encryption cipher for the VLAN interface. This example uses tkip as the encryption cipher..

Type this command to specify the WPA key management type on the radio interface.

```
router#interface dot11radio0
router(config-if)#encryption vlan 3 mode ciphers tkip
```

Bind SSID to a VLAN.

In order to enable the SSID on this interface, bind the SSID to the VLAN in SSID configuration mode.

```
routervlan 3
```

Configure the SSID with WPA-PSK authentication.

You need to configure open or network EAP authentication first in the SSID configuration mode to enable WPA key management. This example configures open authentication.

```
router#interface dot11radio0
router#ssid wpa-shared
router#authentication open
```

Now, enable WPA key management on the SSID. The key management cipher tkip is already configured for this VLAN.

```
router(config-if-ssid)#authentication key-management wpa
```

Configure the WPA-PSK authentication on the SSID.

```
router(config-if-ssid)#wpa-psk ascii 1234567890
```

!--- 1234567890 is the pre-shared key value for this SSID. Ensure that the same key is specified for this SSID at the client side.

Enable VLAN on the radio interface.

```
router#interface Dot11Radio 0.3
router#encapsulation dot1Q 3
router#bridge-group 3
```